# Copy rows col. A to col. B, butkeep current cell value in Column B. (Excel)

Tags: excel, copy, excel-2010, vba

I am searching and trying, nothing seems to work so I hope someone is here to the rescue.

**Problem:**
In Office Excel (2010), Column A has 5 rows. Each row has a simple text value.
In column B only row 4 has a text value.

I would love to copy all 5 rows from column A to column B with one copy paste.
Is it possible (in Excel) to block cell B4, so copy paste doesn't remove the text value in B4?

PS> Ofcourse 5 rows would not be a problem, I have hunderds of rows in column A and trying to do a macro for the task..Help would be highly appreaceated.

**EDIT**

The table is simple:

```
        Col a               Col B              Col B after copy/paste
r1.     this is text        -blank cell-       this is text
r2.     this is text 2      -blank cell-       this is text 2
r3.     this is text 3      -blank cell-       this is text 3
r4.     this is text 4      Titel ect          Titel ect
r5.     this is text 5      -blank cell-       this is text 5
```

Comment: show a screen shots before and after of what you need... have you tried anything (with macrorecorder it's will go quite easy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution is to take column C and run the formula (starting with first row)
 `=If(B1="",A1,B1)` 
down the column. It just says to give you what is in column A should column B is blank, otherwise give you what is in B.

Then you can just copy the column and use special paste (value) to get rid of the formula and be left with a merged (priority on column B) list.

Answer (score 1):

A way is to sort col B (together with col A) and just copy and paste over from col A to col B